# How to diff records within same file

Tags: parsing, awk, sed

I have following file format:

```
AAA-12345~TRAX~~AAAAAAAAAAAA111111ETC
AAA-12345~RCV~~BBBBBBBBBBBB222222ETC
BBB-78900~TRAX~~CCCCCCCCCCCC444444ETC
BBB-78900~RCV~~DDDDDDDDDDDD555555ETC
CCC-65432~TRAX~~HHHHHHHHHHHH888888ETC
```

All lines are in pairs and each pair is identical up single ~.
Sometimes there are orphans like last record which has TRAX but no RCV.
Question is: using bash utilies like sed or awk or commands like grep or cut how do I find and display orphans only?

Comment: extend your input to present multiple possible "orphans"

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please use code tags for your samples and edit your post with correct details and with more informative details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F~ '{a[$1]+=1} END{for(key in a) if(a[key]==1){print key}}'
```

This is just loading the first field (split by tilde) as they key of an array and incrementing the value for that key each time it's found. Then when the file is finished, it iterates the array and prints out key's with just 1 for the value.

Comment: END has the role to stop dumping to array?

Comment: `awk` processes a file line by line. `END` just says "Once you are done processing every line...". That being said, I like Cyrus's answer below piping a simple cut or awk to uniq. I would imagine that `uniq` is going to be faster than loading and iterating an awk array. That being said, if you want to do more processing as you iterate, then you can stick with awk.